# How to acknowledge the processing of a group of messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I am lost in the jungle of AWS. I wish to acknowledge the process of a group of messages but i don't know what can be done.

I use a SQS queue to push messages then process them by a specific handler based on the message type. These messages could be grouped by an emitter id or something else. What is the common way to acknowledge the processing of a group of messages?

Comment: Pub/sub to interested subscribers via SNS is one option.

Answer (score 2):

In SQS you simply call [delete-message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/delete-message.html) with each message's receipt handle to "acknowledge" the message, i.e. inform SQS that the message has been successfully processed. To delete more than one message in a single call you would use [delete-message-batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/delete-message-batch.html). The AWS SDK you are using should have both of those methods available, but you didn't mention which programming language you are using in your question.

If you are using some sort of wrapper on top of SQS, like JMS, then it may provide something like that, but you haven't mentioned that you are using anything like that in your question.

If you're using the AWS Lambda SQS integration, it handles deleting the messages for you automatically when the function returns a non-error response.

If you are trying to inform some other application that you have successfully processed all the messages it enqueued, then you would need to use another method to accomplish that, such as SNS, or another SQS queue, etc.